# Trying to loop with v-for but the value doesn't show when accessing by its property name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to this framework and also javascript. I tried to finish the project, but somehow I could not access the value by using its property name.

Here's the situation. I've set up

```
computed () {
  places () {
  var idsToFind = this.$store.getters.loadedTrip(this.id).places
  var places = this.$store.state.loadedPlaces.filter(item => idsToFind.includes(item.id))
  return places.map((place, i) => {
    return {
      place: place,
      place2: this.$store.state.loadedPlaces.filter(item => idsToFind.includes(item.id)).slice(1)[i]
    }
  })
} 
}
```

As you can see, there are **place** and **place2** being returned. The difference of both is that the second one is not returning the first value.

And, I loop through it like

```
<div v-for="place in places" :key="place.id">
  <div>{{ place.place.name }}</div>
  <div>{{ place.place.location }}</div>
  <div>{{ place.place.budget }}</div>
   ...... etc....
  <div>{{ place.place2.name }}</div>
```

It said `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

However, when I tried to show it by not giving its property name.

```
<div v-for="place in places" :key="place.id">
  <div>{{ place.place.name }}</div>
   ......
  <div>{{ place.place2 }}</div>
```

It loops through and shows the objects correctly as I expected without any error. However, I'd like to show only the value in name property.

Thank you

Comment: why are you doing `slice(1)[i]`?

Comment: I think the simplest is `<div v-if="place.place2">{{ place.place2.name }}</div>`

Comment: @RoyJ In order to show the next value of array in the same element, I eliminated the first value and loop it.

Comment: @acdcjunior It actually works! Can I know how it works? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
<div>{{ place.place2.name }}</div>
```

Yields, as you say, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` because it is trying to get name at a point where `.place2` is not yet initialized.

To prevent that from happening, to prevent displaying when it has not yet been initialized, use a conditional (`v-if`):

```
<div v-if="place.place2">{{ place.place2.name }}</div>
```